# java code that allow to enter some words to it until I enter a space, then it output the same string with dash

Tags: java, string, char

I need a java code that allow to enter some words to it untill I enter a space,
then it output the same string with dash (-) between words.
this is my try:

```
import  javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class tst4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String S;
        int i=0;

        do{
            S = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("input S: ");           
            while( i<S.length() ){
                         i++;
           }

        } white( (int)S != 32 );  // space is equal to 32 in ASCII
        System.out.println( S );

}
```

if the input is:

```
thank(enter)
you(enter)
all(enter)
(space)
```

the output will be:

```
tnank-you-all
```

Comment: Can't cast a String to int. You need to parse the String.

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: What do you mean by _"until I enter a space"_... you mean they can continue to type sentences until they enter **just** a space? cause there are spaces between words... oh and its `while` not `white`.

Comment: "enter some words until I enter a space, then output the same string with dash between words": there will be no dash between words because the dashes would replace the spaces...of which there are none.  Unless you need to include ALL whitespace, in which case, you should tell us that.

Comment: I want you to help me with stopping the program when I enter space

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your homework (don't tell the professor):

```
import java.io.*;
public class whatever {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String str;
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null && !str.equals(" ")) {
            buffer.append(str);
        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString().replace(" ", "-");
    }
}
```

You must put it in a file called `whatever.java`.

Comment: if I input any word it has to take it, but if I iput space, it will stop asking me to input words. this is the big problem to me.

Comment: Do you mean pressing enter? Pressing enter here will dismiss the dialog and print out the appropriate thing. If this is just on the command line, I'll post a revised version for that.

Comment: I mean when I enter a string then pressing enter, it will ask me again to enter a new string repeatedly until the space is inserted, after enter space it will stop asking me to enter a new string.

Comment: So, it will stop asking for a string after you enter a string with spaces. Do you want the command line or GUI?

Comment: command line (not GUI.
if I enter this:


thank (enter)

you(enter)
all(enter)
(space)(enter)
-------- output:
thank-you-all

Comment: Now I understand what you are supposed to do. I'm posting the correct version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33931/discussion-between-tbodt-and--)

Comment: any new mr.tbodt or others?

Comment: not worked (6 errors).
and I prefer using :javax.swing.JOptionPane

Comment: I will fix some obvious answers I see in my post, but I don't have the javac in front of me, so you should tell me what the errors are

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ReplaceSpacesWithHyphens {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input String: ").trim().replace(' ', '-'));
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This code gets input from a `JOptionPane`, replaces spaces with hyphens, and then prints it to the console.

So if you enter, *I entered this text into the JOptionPane* it prints to the console saying, *I-entered-this-text-into-the-JOptionPane*